# After installing msysgit, AnkhSVN tries to use the wrong SSH executable file

Tags: svn, git, ankhsvn, pageant

I have recently installed msysgit on my machine (its running Windows 7) to use Git for some projects. A lot of my projects are under SVN, in which I use AnkhSVN in Visual Studio 2008 to commit etc.

Since I have installed msysgit everytime I try to commit, update etc inside Visual Studio, the program C:\msysgit\bin\ssh.exe loads up, asks for my password, then Ankh throws an exception.

I currently use Pageant to save my login credentials for SVN - I have TortoiseSVN installed, which is still working fine...

Has anybody got any suggestions to get Anhk working again - without uninstalling msysgit?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AnkhSVN (or actually SharpSvn) like most subversion clients uses the common Subversion configuration (stored in %APPDATA%\Subversion and/or the registry). If it doesn't find the configured ssh (by default ssh.exe) it uses its own ssh client SharpPlink, just like TortoiseSVN uses TortoisePlink.

In your case AnkhSVN finds your ssh.exe and assumes that you want to use that instead of its builtin ssh. You can fix this by setting an explicit ssh client in the Subversion configuration, or by removing the ssh.exe from your path.
(The easiest way to explicitly set a ssh client is setting it from TortoiseSVN's settings or via the SVN_SSH environment variable)

Comment: Cheers - I set the SSH variable in the config file to point to TortoisePlink... For those interested (Win7) -> In C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\config ->

ssh = "C:\\Program Files\\TortoiseSVN\\bin\\TortoisePlink.exe"

Comment: @Chalkey Thanks for the comment - that helped. It may also help to restart Visual Studio after you make that change in the config file.

Answer (score 1):

If you check

- **Visual Studio > Tools > Options >
  Source Control**

you should be able to select the Source Control plugin you want.

Installing msysgit may have overridden the AnkhSVN setting.

If it's not there then I'm not sure what to suggest.

Comment: Its still at AnkhSVN, it seems to be something with the ssh.exe that fires up. I thought maybe its running as a service but I cant find nothing.

Comment: That suggests to me that Ankh is mis-configured somehow then. This isn't a lot of help though - sorry - I can't find any configuration files in my version of Ankh just DLLs (perhaps something was overwritten). I was hoping it was an easy fix which is why I posted my answer - I suspected it wouldn't be though when I saw your rep :) Good luck!